# Grammar that allows arbitrary rules order

Tags: clojure, dsl, context-free-grammar, instaparse

I'm (trying) to design a domain-specific language (I called it "Fahrenheit") for designing citation styles.

A program written in Fahrenheit:

- MUST have exactly one `citation` block
- MAY have zero or more `macro` blocks.

Here's a simplified yet valid example:

```
macro m1
  "Hello World!"
end

macro m2
  "Hello World!"
end

citation
  "Hello World!"
end
```

This grammar will recognise the above code as syntactically correct:

```
style = macro* citation

(*  example of macro definition

    macro hw
        "Hello World!"
    end

    *)

macro = <'macro'> #'[a-z0-9]+' statement+ end

citation = <'citation'> statement+ end

statement = #'".*?"'

<end> = <'end'>
```

However the ordering of "blocks" (e.g `macro` or `citation`) shouldn't matter.

**Question:** How should I change my grammar so that it recognises the following program as syntactically correct?

```
macro m1
  "Hello World!"
end

citation
  "Hello World!"
end

macro m2
  "Hello World!"
end
```

*PS: I'm intending to add other optional blocks which order is also irrelevant.*

Comment: shot in the dark: `style = macro* citation macro*` ?

Comment: @cfrick Thanks for this. I didn't mention that I have other kinds of blocks whose order are also irrelevant. I would prefer a solution where I don't have to "hardcode" all the different permutations.

Comment: The other "non-citation"-rules could be combined into something else `others = macros | something` and then use `others*`

Comment: @cfrick Oh I see so then I could just do `style = others* citation others*` ? I'll try that.

Comment: @cfrick That worked! Thanks a lot. Do you want to put that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 0..n rules you can put them before or after the `citation`.  E.g.

```
style = tools* citation tools*
tools = macro | foo | bar
...
```